# How to derive class with decorated method?

Tags: python, oop, jinja2, cherrypy

I have several similar python cherrypy applications

**application_one.py**

```
import cherrypy

class Class(object):

    @cherrypy.tools.jinja(a='a', b='b')
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return {
            'c': 'c'
        }
```

**application_two.py**

```
import cherrypy

class Class(object):

    @cherrypy.tools.jinja(a='a2', b='b2')
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return {
            'c': 'c2'
        }
```

....

**application_n.py**

```
import cherrypy

class Class(object):

    @cherrypy.tools.jinja(a='aN', b='bN')
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return {
            'c': 'cN'
        }
```

I want to make parent class and derive it in all applications.
Something like this

**parent.py**

```
import cherrypy

class ParentClass(object):

    _a = None
    _b = None
    _c = None

    @cherrypy.tools.jinja(a=self._a, b=self._b)
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return {
            'c': self._c
        }
```

**application_one.py**

```
import parent

class Class(ParentClass):

    _a = 'a'
    _b = 'b'
    _c = 'c'
```

application_two.py

```
import parent

class Class(ParentClass):

    _a = 'a2'
    _b = 'b2'
    _c = 'c2'
```

How to send params for index method decorator from derived classes?

**Now I get error**

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators are applied *when you define the class*. When defining a class, you are not running a method and thus `self` is not defined. There is no instance for `self` to refer to.

You'd have to use a metaclass instead, that adds the decorator when building the subclass, or you'd have to use a class decorator, that applies the right decorator after the class has been defined.

The class decorator could be:

```
def add_decorated_index(cls):
    @cherrypy.tools.jinja(a=cls._a, b=cls._b)
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return {
            'c': self._c
        }

    cls.index = index
    return cls
```

then apply this to the subclasses:

```
import parent

@parent.add_decorated_index
class Class(parent.ParentClass):
    _a = 'a'
    _b = 'b'
    _c = 'c'
```